# scanning of queues cmd _error _fatal _notqtstr value <sqyd> is not a quoted string

Tags: unix, scripting, ksh

```
#!/bin/ksh
for line in `cat $file.txt` 
do 
$home/mqscmd.exe scan $line \queue_manager="Sqyd"
$line
done
```

here when I introduce \queue_manager="sqyd" I get the following error,.. I really need to mention the queue manager to scan the queue.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/ksh
while IFS= read -r line
do 
    "$home"/mqscmd.exe scan "$line" 'queue_manager="Sqyd"'
    "$line"
done < file.txt
```

Use a while-read loop as demonstrated to iterate over the lines of a file. The for loop you show in your question iterates over the *words* of a file.

It sounds like the mqscmd.exe program needs to see the literal quotes, so use the quoting mechanism shown: inner double quotes protected by the outer single quotes. Alternately you could omit the output quotes and esacape the double quotes:  `queue_manager=\"Sqyd\"`